# unable to edit css with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, hidden-field

I am trying to edit my form with these simple

testings:

```
<span id="a">30 <span id="aa" style="display:none;"><input type="text" id="aa" name="q"/></span></span>
<span id="cq"><a href="javascript:changeQty()">Change</a></span>
<span id="cq2" style="display:none"><a href="javascript:save()">save</a></span>

<script>
  function changeQty(){
    document.getElementById("a").style.display="hidden";
    document.getElementById("aa").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("cq").style.display="hidden";
    document.getElementById("cq2").style.display="inline";
  }
</script>
```

But strangely,my attempt to hide the fields are not working. But I can view the hidden fields when I click on `Change` link. Whats wrong I am doing ?

Comment: You have a `span` with an `id` of `aa` and inside that an `input` with an `id` of `aa` this is invalid.

Answer (score 7):

There is no `hidden` attribute for `display`, you need to use `none`.

```
function changeQty(){
  document.getElementById("a").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("aa").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("cq").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("cq2").style.display="inline";
}
```

Comment: "hidden" is a valid value for *visibility*, but not *display*.

Comment: I wouldn't say the HTML is the problem here. Yes it helps to have nicer naming conventions so you don't get confused however.

Comment: I take that back as per my comment on the question the HTML is invalid. The ID of `aa` is both on the 2nd `span` and then `input` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You have done two very simple mistake

1. At javascript use vale "none" for display style attribute for hidden a element
2. The element "aa" is the child element of element "a". so when you use 
   **document.getElementById("a").style.display="none";**
   also hides the element "aa"

so the final solution you may desire is as follows

```
<span id="a">30</span>
<span id="aa" style="display:none;"><input type="text" id="aa" name="q"/></span>
<span id="cq"><a href="javascript:changeQty()">Change</a></span>
<span id="cq2" style="display:none"><a href="javascript:save()">save</a></span>

<script>
  function changeQty() {
    document.getElementById("a").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("aa").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("cq").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("cq2").style.display="inline";
   }
</script>
```